# How to configure a GitHub action to to a static S3 website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, github-actions, amazon-iam

I am working to set up a GitHub action that uploads a couple static files (html, css) to my S3 bucket, which is being served as a static website by AWS.

I have a couple policies set up but they don't seem to be allowing for the correct permissions to allow the action's aws cli tool to connect to S3.

I have a user named `github_runner` with the attached policy for accessing the bucket in question:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3AccessWebBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myrealbucket-web",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myrealbucket-web/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And on the bucket I have this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SourceIP",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myrealbucket-web",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myrealbucket-web/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "0.0.0.0/32", // my subdomains I want to allow access to
                        "0.0.0.0/32"
                    ]
                },
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:iam::11111111:user/github_runner"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myrealbucket-web/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::11111111:user/github_runner"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myrealbucket-web"
        }
    ]
}
```

I imagine part of the problem is the SourceIP Sid, which I am using to block access to my website besides from within my org. It's not an extremely confidential website, but this does enough for me on a security level to keep out snoopers.

Finally, when I run the action I see:

```
Run aws s3 mv ./index.html ***
  aws s3 mv ./index.html ***
  aws s3 mv ./style.css ***
  aws s3 mv ./script.js ***
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ***
    AWS_REGION: ***
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
move failed: ./index.html to ***/index.html An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

I've tried adjusting the `ArnNotEquals` to also exclude the user arn with `aws:PrincipalArn` to no avail.

I've also tried adding and removing some of the s3 permissions but can't seem to land on the right set-up. Is the global deny stopping my upload? Shouldn't the bucket and user policies make a path for my runner to upload data?

Comment: I have something very similar working on a bucket I own. I just checked and instead of using `ArnNotEquals` I'm using `NotPrincipal` and specifying the IAM role there https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html

Comment: In the SourceIP rule? I don't think I can mix using `"Principal": "*"` to deny access to most users and `"NotPrincipal"` with my user arn.

Comment: You would replace `Principal *` with `NotPrincipal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly what you describe working with this configuration:

```
        {
            "Sid": "SourceIP",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::11111111:user/github_runner"]},
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myrealbucket-web",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myrealbucket-web/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "0.0.0.0/32", // my subdomains I want to allow access to
                        "0.0.0.0/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

You'll need to add any other IAM roles/users to that principal list that also need access to the bucket.

Comment: Great! That worked. Might have been because I only had one user, but I had to change the NotPrincipal part to 
`"NotPrincipal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111:user/github_runner" },` to quell a syntax error.

I assume this works because using NotPrincipal implies a `Principal: *` right?

Do you have thoughts on why this method works and not as a condition?

Comment: The `SoureArn` part of my answer was a typo, because I did a copy/paste out of your question and I copied too much. Sorry about that. And yes, `NotPrincipal` means everyone except this one principal. So it's `"*" minus "arn:aws:iam::11111111:user/github_runner"`